# How can a Windows 8 app be allowed to open/create files of any type?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am writing an app for Windows 8 metro and I need to be able to open/create files of any type.

However, according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#documents_library), even if an app declares that the `documentsLibrary` capability, it can only open/create files that are defined in the file type associations section.

How can I allow my app to open or create files of any type?

Comment: Is using a desktop app or service to access the files an option?

Comment: No, it needs to access them directly from the app. I'm assuming that both of those options would mean it can't run on Windows RT.

Comment: An RT app lives in a cocoon, there is no such thing as 'all files'

Comment: It only needs to open files it created, but of any file type.

Answer (score 2):

No. That page only refers to access to files **without user's knowledge**. That means you can enumerate them and read them without user explicitly selecting one.

When using `Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker`, user can select any file from anywhere. But this must be done by user, not automatically by application. Same thing with saving.

Example: [Access and save files using the file picker sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba/sourcecode?fileId=43705&pathId=2647585)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that without adding any capabilities, the app is allowed to create any type of file in the "Downloads" folder.

This code works, even without the `documentsLibrary` capability:

```
StorageFolder folder = await Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.CreateFolderAsync("folder");
StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("myfile.txt");
```

The ".txt" file type did not need to be declared in the file type associations.

**Update:** [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.downloadsfolder) on msdn explains the permissions for the download folder.